# How to convert a Tableau Packaged Workbook (twbx) to Tableau Workbook (twb)?

Tags: tableau-api

I am currently working with a Tableau Packaged Workbook and looking to convert it back to Tableau Workbook, i.e. the pure file without data extract in the file. I've tried to open up the file in Tableau, go to data source and select "live" connection instead of "Extract". The file size did decrease dramatically, but the file name extension didn't change, instead stayed as ".twbx" instead of ".twb". Can I just change it  manually, will that mess up the file? Thanks!

BTW, I am using Tableau 9.0 Desktop.

Answer (score 4):

Just found the answer. Actually, we need to open the twb file in Tableau desktop and then go to file - save as - save as type - Tableau Workbook.

Answer (score 3):

Just open your tableau click "Save as" now save your file as .twb instaed of .twbx

```
it will help!
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to approach this is to break the .twbx into its constituent elements.

**The .twbx is really just a zip file**, so just like .docx and .xlsx files, you can rename the file (or better yet, a copy) with a .zip extension then right-click and Extract All from the context menu.  (I'm on Windows and unfortunately cannot offer Apple or Linux equivalents.)

Once the files have been extracted into the resulting folder, the .twb file will be in the root whilst the .tde data will found nested in folders cunningly called, Data --> Datasources.

Comment: @py_noob:
Were you able to extract the contents of the file after decompressing it?

Comment: no, I'm still trying to figure out how to programmatically convert a twb to a twbx

Comment: I apologize for the delay in noticing your response.  The way I would attempt to handle this situation is through some scripting, maybe with PowerShell.  Or write a C# app.  7Zip offers a command line interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can also right click on a .twbx file in finder or file explorer and choose unpackage workbook